# How do I resolve this NullPointerException related to retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to make a Pokedex app that fetches pokemon data from API using retrofit2.
It logs the following error when I try to run it
**Error:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                
Process: com.example.pokemonapp, PID: 10766                                                                                            
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.example.pokemonapp.PokeAdapter.<init>, parameter pokes                                                                                      
    at com.example.pokemonapp.PokeAdapter.<init>(Unknown Source:7)                                                                                          
    at com.example.pokemonapp.MainActivity$getPokemon$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:31)                                                                                          
    at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$retrofit2-DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)                                                                                             
    at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)                                                                                               
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)                                                                                                  
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                                                      
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)                                                                                                          
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)                                                                                                              
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)                                                                                                                    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                                       
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)                                                                                                                            
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var adapter: PokeAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getPokemon()
    }

    private fun getPokemon() {
            val pokeball: Call<PokeApiResponse> = PokeInterface.ApiService.pokeInstance.getPokemonList()
            pokeball.enqueue(object: Callback<PokeApiResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<PokeApiResponse>,
                    response: Response<PokeApiResponse>
                ) {
                    val pokedex = response.body()
                    if(pokedex!= null)
                    {
                        Log.d("CHECK", pokeball.toString())
                        adapter = PokeAdapter(this@MainActivity, pokedex.pokemons)
                        val pokeList = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.pokemonList)
                        pokeList.adapter = adapter
                        pokeList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                    }
                }


                override fun onFailure(call: Call<PokeApiResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("CHECK", "Error in fetching Pokemon", t)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

**ApiService.kt**

```
const val BASE_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/"

interface PokeInterface{
    @GET("pokedex.json")
    fun getPokemonList() : Call<PokeApiResponse>

    //https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json

    object ApiService{
        val pokeInstance: PokeInterface
        init{
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
            pokeInstance = retrofit.create(PokeInterface::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

**PokeApiResponse.kt**

```
data class PokeApiResponse(
    val pokemons: List<Poke>
)
```

**Poke.kt**

```
data class Poke(
    val name: String,
    val img: String
)
```

**PokeAdapter.kt**

```
class PokeAdapter(val context: Context, val pokes: List<Poke>): RecyclerView.Adapter<PokeAdapter.PokemonViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PokemonViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
        return PokemonViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return pokes.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PokemonViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val pokemon = pokes[position]
        holder.pokeTitle.text = pokemon.name
    }

    class PokemonViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var pokeImage = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pokeImage)
        var pokeTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pokeName)
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
```

In MainActivity.kt I try logging the data fetched using the tag "CHECK", it logs the following message:

> retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@6d104a9

Earlier when I hadn't implemented `RecyclerView`, retrofit was fetching the data correctly and the fetched data was also logged correctly under the tag "CHECK", however now it keeps giving the `DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall` message.

I have spent hours trying to find a solution online, but nothing works.
Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the NPE could be from your Log

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<PokeApiResponse>, response: Response<PokeApiResponse>) {
    val pokedex = response.body()
    if (pokedex != null) {
        Log.d("CHECK", "Received ${pokedex.pokemons.size} Pokemon")
        adapter = PokeAdapter(this@MainActivity, pokedex.pokemons)
        val pokeList = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.pokemonList)
        pokeList.adapter = adapter
        pokeList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    }
}
```

Try to log the **pokedex** list instead of the **pokeball**

Please try with this array name as your json suggests

```
data class PokeApiResponse(
    @SerializedName("pokemon")
    val pokemons: List<Poke>
)
```

Comment: I tried to log the pokedex list as you suggested, but now it isn't logging anything at all under that tag.
The error also seems to have changed to a different NullPointerException:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at com.example.pokemonapp.MainActivity$getPokemon$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:31)
at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$retrofit2-DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
.
.
.

Comment: thats because pokemons is null, please check with a breakpoint at the log line what is coming as null and evaluate

Comment: I added an extra peace of code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be 1 of the 2 following scenarios (or perhaps a mix of the 2)

1)
The GSON library does not respect Kotlin nullability.

Your model `PokeApiResponse` has a list inside it called `pokemons`.
This list is marked as non-null.

But when GSON is parsing the JSON data, the JSON response does not contain a list with that name, and GSON then simply assigns the value of the `pokemon` list to null.
It can do this, because it internally uses Java Reflection to access the field.

Then when you get the response in your Activity and try to access it, the field will be null, thus you get a NullPointerException.
According to your code and model, it should not be possible. But because GSON uses Java Reflection, it is possible. This is a major reason why GSON is not a great library to use. It's easy, but also full of major downsides like this.

I have personally spent a few weeks to completely get rid of GSON in our project, and replaced it with Moshi (https://github.com/square/moshi) which will handle cases like this in a much better and controlled way.

2)
If you have `minifyEnabled` set to `true` in your `build.gradle` file, it will obfuscate your code.
This can cause your list called `pokemons` in your code, to be called `a` in the compiled code.
Then when GSON wants to parse the JSON data to your model, the JSON data has a list called `pokemons`, but your model list is called `a`, so it can't parse it correctly.

To fix this, add `@SerializedName("pokemons")` to your model (and all fields in all your models)

```
data class PokeApiResponse(
    @SerializedName("pokemons")
    val pokemons: List<Poke>
)
```